# JBehave: Don't throw Assert Exception

Tags: testing, bdd, jbehave

I just started using JBehave for BDD and I have one big problem.
Everytime an assert fails, an exception in my Netbeans environment is thrown and the other tests aren't executed.
But I want it to mark this test as failed and execute the other tests.
I've searched a lot, but there was no solution to my problem.

Story:

```html
Narrative:
In order to manage our stock efficiently
As a logistic employee
I would like to handle returns and changes in a proper way
 
 
Scenario:  Return of a phone
 
Given there is an empty stock
And there are 2 A phone(s) in stock
When a customer returns the not damaged A phone 
Then there should be 2 A phone(s) in stock

Scenario:  Exchange of a phone
 
Given there is an empty stock
And there are 5 A phone(s) in stock
And there are 5 B phone(s) in stock
When a customer changes his A phone for a B phone
Then there should be 6 A phone(s) in stock
And there should be 4 B phone(s) in stock
```

ScenarioLoader

```
public class LogisticScenarios extends JUnitStory {

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    URL storyURL = null;
    try {
        // This requires you to start Maven from the project directory
        storyURL = new URL("file://" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "/src/main/resources/stories/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
            .useStoryLoader(
            new LoadFromRelativeFile(storyURL)).useStoryReporterBuilder(
                    new StoryReporterBuilder().withFormats(Format.HTML));
}

@Override
public List<CandidateSteps> candidateSteps() {
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new LogisticSteps())
            .createCandidateSteps();
}

@Override
@Test
public void run() {
    try {
        super.run();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Steps

```
public class LogisticSteps extends Embedder {

List<Phone> stock;

@Given("there is an empty stock")
public void initializeStock() {
    stock = new LinkedList();
}

@Given("there are $quantity $type phone(s) in stock")
public void fillStock(String quantity, String type) {
    stock = stock == null ? new LinkedList() : stock;
    PhoneType pType = type.equals("A") ? PhoneType.A : PhoneType.B;

    addPhonesToStock(pType, Integer.parseInt(quantity));
}

@When("a customer returns the not damaged $type phone")
public void customerReturnsPhone(String type) {
    PhoneType ptype = type.equals("A") ? PhoneType.A : PhoneType.B;
    addPhonesToStock(ptype, 1);
}

@When("a customer changes his $type1 phone for a $type2 phone")
public void customerExchangesPhone(String type1, String type2) {
    PhoneType pType1 = type1.equals("A") ? PhoneType.A : PhoneType.B;
    PhoneType pType2 = type2.equals("A") ? PhoneType.A : PhoneType.B;

    stock.add(new Phone(pType1));
    removePhoneFromStock(pType2);
}

@Then("there should be $quantity $type phone(s) in stock")
public void thePositionReturnedShouldBe(String quantity, String type) {
    PhoneType pType = type.equals("A") ? PhoneType.A : PhoneType.B;

    Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(quantity), countPhonesFromType(pType));
}

private void removePhoneFromStock(PhoneType type) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stock.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (stock.get(i).getType() == type) {
            stock.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private int countPhonesFromType(PhoneType type) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Phone p : stock) {
        if (p.getType() == type) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private void addPhonesToStock(PhoneType type, int quantity) {
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        stock.add(new Phone(type));
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

General behavior of JBehave. In a scenario if a step fails (*exception is thrown*) it does not execute next steps of that scenario (*Marks them as not performed*), But 2nd scenario after that will be executed. Now, if your next scenario depends on the result of 1st scenario then it will also fail, right.

now, if you see you have:

```
try {
        super.run();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To over come this setting you can try to catch the exception in your code and take necessary step as per your choice.

Place where you are doing assert use try catch like this:

```
try{
   Assert.assertEquals();
} catch (Exception e){
   <your steps> <record the result or just move forward>
}
```